# Transactional Email List

Tags: email, email-templates

Does anyone know where I can find a list of all the triggers for a transactional email?  Some of them are obvious or self explanatory (such as "forgot password" or "new order"), but others are not as self evident, and even the existing email templates give little help on what they should be about, such as "friend email template".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/comprehensive-list-of-magento-transactional-emails-and-their-designs) seems fairly exhaustive